# Confused Drag in VStack using SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, stack, drag

I have a list of items inside Form, Section and VStack. I want to be able to drag the inner item but the entire Section/VStack is dragged.

The problem is illustrated with the first section in the code below which use a VStack. The second section doesn't use a VStack and works fine (individual items are dragged).

```
enum  TestData: String, CaseIterable {
  case one, two, three
}

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Form {
      Section {
        VStack {
          ForEach(TestData.allCases.reversed(), id:\.self) { text in
            Text(text.rawValue)
            .onDrag {
              NSItemProvider(object: text.rawValue as NSString)
            }
          }
        }
      }

      Section {
        ForEach(TestData.allCases, id:\.self) { text in
          Text(text.rawValue)
          .onDrag {
            NSItemProvider(object: text.rawValue as NSString)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to drag an individual item inside a Section/VStack?

Comment: ... so what are you trying to solve, if the second example works as you intended?

Comment: My use case requires the VStack. I synthesized my requirement  to illustrate the issue. And to, perhaps, let others know that this problem or l limitation exists.

Answer (score 0):

Form Section is a particular struct that has a Parent, a Content and a Footer.

Parent is the view it belong to, in your example the Form.
Content is a View, in particular Section by default are vertical stacks.
Therefore it is not necessary to insert the elements of your list into an additional V Stack, because it's as if they already were.

In this example, I added another element without a VStack and SwiftUI handles it flawlessly.
On the latter I have not added the drag and in fact it's not draggable, like I want.

```
Section {
        ForEach(TestData.allCases.reversed(), id:\.self) { text in
          Text(text.rawValue)
              .onDrag {
                NSItemProvider(object: text.rawValue as NSString)
              }
        }
        Text("Test")
              .background(Color.red)
      }
```

[image]

If you add another VStack, SwiftUI has a hard time understanding him, because he sees it as as single body and draw it like a single cell in the section.

Comment: You're right, you can re-write my example to make it work; however, I mentioned above (George) that I synthesized my requirement to illustrate the issue. And to, perhaps, let others know that this problem or l limitation exists. My use case requires the VStack.